# Airflow DAG is triggered twice by scheduler. Weekly DAG

Tags: airflow, scheduler

Airflow DAG is triggered twice on Monday for below configurations.

When I use `30 11 * * 1` cron expression, DAG doesn't trigger at all. So figured out I have to add one more * to the expression. 
`30 11 * * 1 *` - It works.

```
default_args:
'start_date': airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(1)
```

DAG :
schedule_interval=`30 11 * * 1 *`, ## This is weekly run on Monday at 11:30.

However, DAG is getting triggered 2 times every Monday. 1 min apart:

- 11:30:05
- 11:30:58

What could be the possible reason?

Answer (score 2):

So finally, I figured out the issue.

Yes it is correct, 5 digit cron expression is correct.
I am using `schedule_interval = 30 11 * * 1  #(Every Monday 11:30 UTC)`

It wasn't working because I had my start_time :

```
'start_date': airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(1)
```

I found this blog on Airflow — Trick to find the exact [start_date] via CRON expression [here](https://medium.com/intage-analytics/airflow-trick-to-find-the-exact-start-date-via-cron-expression-23b5351007b)!

If it's a weekly job, your start_date should be a week ago. 
So I changed it to `'start_date': airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(7)`

Now it is working fine.

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

The 6 digits cron expression is incorrect, the first one you input is correct. How many times did you run the DAG? 
I suggest you try to run `schedule_interval=@weekly` first and see what happens ?

Comment: First I had it scheduled with 5 digit expression, never triggered. So then I looked at Airflow Document and there I saw, total 6 digit, with year as well. So I changed it to 6 digit and it triggered the DAG. Problem is it triggers twice. And I have no clue, why it does that. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

The cron parser that airflow is using interprets the 6th place as seconds (as you can see here: https://github.com/kiorky/croniter/blob/master/src/croniter/tests/test_croniter.py#L14 ).

I'm assuming that your DAG finishes in under a minute.  The next scheduler loop, it sees that the cron schedule still matches (on the 58th second), so it starts the DAG again.

I was having the same issue, because the Airflow documentation linked to a wikipedia entry about cron that showed 6 entries.  6 entries is non standard, and there is more than one implementation.  Anyway, for Airflow, the 6th entry is interpreted as seconds.

Your 5 place cron expression should work.  Maybe try again? However, change the dag id, or you may run into weird behaviour: From https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AIRFLOW/Common+Pitfalls : `Changing schedule interval always requires changing the dag_id, because previously run TaskInstances will not align with the new schedule interval`